# Keep database lookup in memory and get values in frequent

Tags: c#

Is there a way to write it in more efficient and modern (Up to date design pattern) way?

```
 static Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> m_LUApplicationParams;
    public string LUApplicationParams(int applicationId, string GuidId, string variable)
            {
                if (m_LUApplicationParams == null)
                {
                    var blLU = new LU();
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    dt = blLU.GetLUApplicationVaribales(applicationId);


                    m_LUApplicationParams = new `Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,string>>();`


                    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {

                        if (!m_LUApplicationParams.ContainsKey(dt.Rows[i]["LangId"].ToString()))
                        {
                            m_LUApplicationParams.Add(dt.Rows[i]["LangId"].ToString(), new Dictionary<string, string>());
                        }


                        m_LUApplicationParams[dt.Rows[i]["LangId"].ToString()].Add(dt.Rows[i]["Variable"].ToString(), dt.Rows[i]["Content"].ToString());                                    }


                }

                return m_LUApplicationParams[GuidId].Where(y => y.Key == variable).FirstOrDefault().Value.ToString();
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

Some quick notes:

- `LUApplicationParams` is not a good method name. It doesn't tell me what it does, and moreover [it isn't even a verb](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4df752aw%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).
- m_LUApplicationParams isn't a good name for a field or property. I'm not a fan of the "m_" naming, it contains an obscure abbreviation or acronym (`LU`), and it doesn't tell me what it contains, which is especially bad considering this is a `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>`.
- I'd move all of the logic inside `if (m_LUApplicationParams == null)` to a separate method. I even wonder whether this would be the right place for such logic (although I have done such things myself).
- `blLU` doesn't tell me anything, even when it is used like `var blLU = new LU();`.
- Why do you do `DataTable dt = new DataTable();`? It's pointless since the next line assigns a value to dt anyway.
- `"LangId"` is used three times. Suppose you ever need to change it: wouldn't it be handier if it were a constant?
- `dt.Rows[i]["LangId"].ToString()` is used three times: then why not assign it to a variable?
- `GuidId` is a parameter and thus [should be CamelCase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2dbyw72%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). But is `GuidId` even a proper name, considering that the other code suggests it is actually an id to identify the langhuage: `"LangId"`?
- What does `variable` represent? Even the field name isn't helping, since that is `"Variable"` also. I'd hate to be the next person to maintain this code since obviously a lot of information is missing from it.
- You do `.FirstOrDefault()` and then immediately use the .Value of the result; but what if there is no value?
- Also, `.FirstOrDefault()` suggests multiple values are possible, is that a possibility you want? And why would the first result be the correct one?
- Why do you do `.ToString()` to the result of `.FirstOrDefault().Value`? Why do you fear that the value of a `Dictionary<string, string>` key-value pair wouldn't be a `string`?
- You do `.Where` and then `.FirstOrDefault`: replace this by `.FirstOrDefault(y => y.Key == variable)`.

---

If you need to fetch a specific value from a DataRow, why not extract such code to a method?

```
private string GetValue(DataRow row, string key)
{
    return row[key].ToString();
}
```

---

Avoid doing `Dictionary.ContainsKey`: if you need to use the value of said key, use [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.TryGetValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
var row = dt.Rows[i];
var languageId = GetValue(row, "LangId");

Dictionary<string,string>() contentByVariable;
if(!m_LUApplicationParams.TryGetValue(languageId, out contentByVariable))
{
    contentByVariable = new Dictionary<string,string>();
}

contentByVariable.Add(GetValue(row, "Variable"), GetValue(row, "Content"));
m_LUApplicationParams[languageId] = contentByVariable;
```

---

But if I were you I'd rethink this entire logic. A `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>` is ugly and unwieldy; IMHO the nested dictionary should be a custom class.

I also feel this code is odd and possible buggy: data is retrieved for an `applicationId` yet this parameter is completely absent in `m_LUApplicationParams`. The `GuidId` that is passed is assumed to be present as a key in `m_LUApplicationParams`, same for the `variable`.

Answer (score 1):

I would make this into a class that is dependency injected as singleton as static's are just a nightmare when it comes to threading and you want different lookups for different applicationId's (your current code doesn't do this). I will use unity in this example as the dependency injection library. (http://unity.codeplex.com/). Also your current method violates the single responsibility principle in my opinion as its doing to much. You don't want to do a where over the items of the dictionary, that is very expensive. Unlike the other answer I don't have a problem with the nested dictionary as it's encapsulated.

First I made an ApplicationParameterLookup class who's sole responsibility is to keep a dictionary for an application id. Then I added a static Lazy, this will keep the default container if the implementing code doesn't want to pass it's own into the static methods. I then added RegisterApplication which instanstiates ApplicationParameterLookup and adds it as an instance to a UnityContainer, this will make it as singleton and on Resolve the load logic will not be called again.

Then I added GetApplicationParameter which takes an application id, guid and variable and will attempt to resolve the ApplicationParameterLookup based on application id, if it can't find one it will register a new one. And finally it calls the instance's GetApplicationParameter.

```
public class ApplicationParameterLookup
{
    private Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> LookupParams = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();
    public ApplicationParameterLookup(int applicationID)
    {
        LookupParams = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();
        DataTable dt = null; //Get from repository

        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            string langId = row["LangId"].ToString();
            Dictionary<string, string> valueDictionary;
            if(!LookupParams.TryGetValue(langId, out valueDictionary))
            {
                valueDictionary = new Dictionary<string,string>();
                LookupParams[langId] = valueDictionary;
            }
            valueDictionary.Add(row["Variable"].ToString(), row["Content"].ToString());
        }
    }

    public string GetApplicationParameter(string guid, string variable)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> valueDictionary;
        if (LookupParams.TryGetValue(guid, out valueDictionary))
        {
            string variableValue;
            if (valueDictionary.TryGetValue(variable, out variableValue))
                return variableValue;
        }
        return null;
    }
    private static Lazy<IUnityContainer> _containerInstance = new Lazy<IUnityContainer>(() => new UnityContainer());
    private static IUnityContainer ApplicationParameterContainer
    {
        get { return _containerInstance.Value; }
    }
    public static ApplicationParameterLookup RegisterApplication(int applicationID, IUnityContainer container = null)
    {
        if (container == null)
            container = ApplicationParameterContainer;
        ApplicationParameterLookup lookup = null;
        lock (container)
        {
            if (!container.IsRegistered<ApplicationParameterLookup>(applicationID.ToString()))
            {
                lookup = new ApplicationParameterLookup(applicationID);
                container.RegisterInstance<ApplicationParameterLookup>(applicationID.ToString(), lookup);
            }
            else
                lookup = container.Resolve<ApplicationParameterLookup>(applicationID.ToString());
        }
        return lookup;
    }        
    public static string GetApplicationParameter(int applicationID, string guid, string variable, IUnityContainer container = null)
    {
        if (container == null)
            container = ApplicationParameterContainer;
        var lookup = container.Resolve<ApplicationParameterLookup>(applicationID.ToString());
        if (lookup == null)
            lookup = RegisterApplication(applicationID, container);
        return lookup.GetApplicationParameter(guid, variable);
    }
}
```